# Google Maps API Dynamic Multiple Polyline Creation

Tags: google-maps, dynamic, google-maps-api-3, polyline, google-polyline

So I have a site under developement and a REST server behind it for a presentation,I'm checking some devices from the site and send the names through a GET on the server.The server finds some geo positioning data from a mySQL DB and returns them to the site as a response to the GET.

I want to dynamically draw a polyline for each different device and add to it any number of positions returned from the DB for each device.

Problem is for a polyline to be created I need:

-- a `markers` array for the markers(one marker for each position I get from the DB)

-- and a `latlngs` array for the position's location on a map

for each device!

The number of devices I check for or the positions I receive for each one of them are not static.I tried creating new arrays with `eval("var " + DeviceID + "_Markers = [];");` but it doesn't seem to work...

Besically what I do right now is:
Get the results from the DB in a very big string which has `$$` between the different devices, `||` between the different positions of the devices and `#` between the fields of each position!
Here is the code that gets and "de-codes" the string:

```
var devArray = respData.split("$$");

for (i=0 ; i < devArray.length ; i++)
{
    var posArray = devArray[i].split("||");
    for (j=posArray.length-1 ; j >= 0 ; j--)
    {
        var data = posArray[j].split("#");
        var DeviceID = data[0];
        var Date = data[1];
        var Latitude = data[2];
        var Longitude = data[3];
        var Altitude = data[4];
        var Angle = data[5];
        var Speed = data[6];
        parent.ifr2.createLocationMarker(DeviceID,Date,Latitude,Longitude,Altitude,Angle,Speed);
    }
}
```

the `createLocationMarker()` calls the specific method on the htmp page that the google maps api is and as it says it creates a new location marker for each position read.

```
    function createLocationMarker(DeviceID,Date,Latitude,Longitude,Altitude,Angle,Speed) {

    var newLocation =  new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude,Longitude);
    var locationMarker = new google.maps.Marker();

    locationMarker.setOptions({
      icon: locationIcon,
      shadow: newShadow,
      draggable: true,
      map: map,
      position: newLocation
    });

    if ((eval("typeof " + DeviceID + "_latlngs") === "undefined") {
        // latlngs Array
        eval("var " + DeviceID + "_latlngs = new google.maps.MVCArray();");

        // markers Array
        eval("var " + DeviceID + "_Markers = [];");

        // displayPath
        eval("var " + DeviceID + "_displayPath = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16) + "' ,strokeOpacity: 1.0, strokeWeight: 2, path: latlngs });");
    }

    eval(DeviceID + "_Markers.push(locationMarker);");
    eval(DeviceID + "_latlngs.push(newLocation);");
    eval(DeviceID + "_displayPath.setPath(" + DeviceID + "_latlngs);");

    locationMarker.setMap(map);

    var content = "<b>Device ID: </b>" + DeviceID + "</br><b>Date: </b>" + Date + "</br><b>Latitude: </b>" + Latitude + "</br><b>Longitude: </b>" + Longitude + "</br><b>Altitude: </b>" + Altitude + "</br><b>Angle: </b>" + Angle + "</br><b>Speed: </b>" + Speed + "Km/h";

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: content,
        disableAutoPan: true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(locationMarker, "dblclick", function() {
        infowindow.open(map,locationMarker);
    });

    map.setCenter(newLocation);
}
```

This seems to create new arrays with `eval` on every point even though they should exist after the first time they are created...
I'm sure there has to be a better way to implement this but I can't find any right now..
Any Idea on how to dynamically create a polyline for each different device and add it's positions in there? (Or a way to make this work,even though I know that `eval` is not a nice way to solve it..)